# MySQL - ошибка при импорте из дампа

Tags: mysql

Есть дамп базы. Пытаюсь сделать импорт, выводит ошибку:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'PAGE_CHECKSUM=1' at line 9

Погуглив, понял, что мой MySQL по дефолту InnoDb , а такая ошибка выводится когда дамп был сделан на другом движке (myisam, например).

Так вот вопрос: как узнать информацию по дампу, если он не импортируется, на каком движке он сделан и как перевести его в стандартный innoDb? Если переводить мой сервер, то затронет ли это другие базы на этом сервере?

Answer (score 2):

PAGE_CHECKSUM - это из движка Aria и импорт скорее всего был из MariaDB, а не родного MySQL. Если про движок, то он должен быть указан в дампе строкой ENGINE=Aria. Соотв-но как вариант - заменить в дампе Aria на MyISAM, а PAGE_CHECKSUM просто вырезать.